# PlatformIO Project Build Error Due to Architecture Mismatch on macOS (arm64 vs x86_64)

Tags: python, pip, esp32, arduino-esp32, platformio

I am trying to build a PlatformIO project for the for my esp32-s3 board on my Macbook M1 (ARM). During the build process, I encountered an error related to an architecture mismatch.

The error message specifically points to an incompatible architecture with the file charset_normalizer/md.cpython-311-darwin.so (a pip charset_normalizer package), stating:

```
ImportError: dlopen(.../charset_normalizer/md.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: ... (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')).
```

Checking the versions of the packages, I see

```
Users/eric/.platformio/penv/.espidf-5.0.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-311-darwin.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64
/Users/eric/.platformio/penv/.espidf-5.0.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/msgpack/_cmsgpack.cpython-311-darwin.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64
/Users/eric/.platformio/penv/.espidf-5.0.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64] [arm64]
/Users/eric/.platformio/penv/.espidf-5.0.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/Users/eric/.platformio/penv/.espidf-5.0.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so (for architecture arm64):    Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
/Users/eric/.platformio/penv/.espidf-5.0.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/charset_normalizer/md__mypyc.cpython-311-darwin.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64
/Users/eric/.platformio/penv/.espidf-5.0.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/charset_normalizer/md.cpython-311-darwin.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64
/Users/eric/.platformio/penv/.espidf-5.0.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yaml/_yaml.cpython-311-darwin.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64
eric@Erics-MBP site-packages %
```

I examined the architecture of the relevant shared object files and found that most are 'arm64', except for
`cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so`, which is a universal binary with both 'x86_64' and 'arm64'. I don't imagine this to be an issue.

Note: PlatformIO version: Using ESP-IDF 5.0.2.

Despite these efforts, the error persists. I've uninstalled every python version there is (platformio uses its own python interpreter so probably not an issue) and manually went in and reinstalled those packages outside and within the virtual env. During those reinstallations I've verified it's installing the ARM binaries and not x86. Why is it asking for x86 on an ARM machine? How can I fix this?

Comment: I had similar issue recently, for me installing `sudo gem install ffi
 ` and `pip uninstall lxml
ARCHFLAGS="-arch arm64" pip install lxml --compile --no-cache-dir` worked for me

Also try to use prefix `arch -arm64 pip ...` to install any dependency libs